# How to configure lazy.nvim with mini-files?

Tags: plugins, neovim

I recently switched to [lazy.nvim](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim) after a few years away. I've installed [mini.nvim](https://github.com/echasnovski/mini.nvim), and want to configure one of the key mappings for [mini-files](https://github.com/echasnovski/mini.nvim/blob/main/readmes/mini-files.md).

Nothing I've tried is working. I'm loading plugins.lua from my lazy.lua, which is as follows:

```
 {
    "echasnovski/mini.nvim",
    version = false,

    config = function()
      require("mini.files").setup({
        mappings = {
          close = "q",
          go_in = "x",
          go_in_plus = "<CR>",
          go_out = "h",
          go_out_plus = "H",
          reset = "<BS>",
          reveal_cwd = "@",
          show_help = "g?",
          synchronize = "=",
          trim_left = "<",
          trim_right = ">",
        },
      })
    end,
  },

  { "Pocco81/auto-save.nvim" },
}
```

How can I do this? See the reference for [mini-files](https://github.com/echasnovski/mini.nvim/blob/main/readmes/mini-files.md) to see the settings options, but it's not picking up my changes (remapping go_in_plus to ).

Is there a proper way to set plugin config in lazy.nvim?

EDIT: It looks like lazyvim has some sort of extra plugin for mini-files, I'm not sure why, [but here is the relevant page](https://www.lazyvim.org/extras/editor/mini-files)